Differential-vertex-deletion equation for graph functions $f(x_1,...,x_n;G)$ on $n$ vertices
I encountered a function $f$ defined over a graph $G$ in my research which does not satisfy a deletion–contraction recurrence but an equation of the form
$$\partial_k f(x_1,...,x_k,..x_n;G)=g(x_k, N_{v_k};G)f(x_,...,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},...,x_n;G\setminus\lbrace v_k\rbrace)$$
for any $k\in\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace$ and $g(x_k;G)$ only depends on the neighbors of $v_k$ in $G$ denoted by $N_{v_k}$.
Generally, this leads in my research to an initial value problem with $f(0;G) = 0$ and a system of ODEs over all $k$.
Assuming sufficient differentiability for $f$, this implies that if $v_k,v_l$ are not neighbors, denoting by $\bar{x}$ the reduced vector $\bar{x}_k=(x_,...,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},...,x_n)$ and $\bar{x}_{k,l}$ the vector without the $l$th and the $k$th entry, then
$$\partial_l\partial_k f(x;G)=g(x_k, N_{v_k};G)\partial_l f(\bar{x}_k;G\setminus\lbrace v_k\rbrace)=g(x_k, N_{v_k};G)g(x_l, N_{v_l};G)f(\bar{x}_{k,l};G\setminus\lbrace v_k,v_l\rbrace)$$
but for $v_k,v_l$ being neighbors, we have
$$\partial_l\partial_k f(x;G)=g(x_k, N_{v_k};G)\partial_l f(\bar{x}_k;G\setminus\lbrace v_k\rbrace)+\partial_l g(x_k, N_{v_k};G) f(\bar{x}_k;G\setminus\lbrace v_k\rbrace).$$
The first term corresponds in its form to the non-neighbor case.
For $g(x_k,N_{x_k};G)=\sum_{l}2x_k(x_k-x_l)$ you can prove, inductively with a lot of calculation effort, that $f(x;G)=\prod_{\langle i,j\rangle}(x_i-x_j)^2$. This example arises from labelings of vertices. Is there a general theory for these kinds of equations in the context of graph theory? Or examples, which are known to yield information about graph structures?
